# ntp sync issue after setting time with date command

Tags: linux, command-line, sync, time, ntp

one of our servers had not accessed the time server for a long time. After access is turned on; my colleague has notice date is wrong and setting time with date command. After this I have restarted the ntp service and sync the time server "ntpdate timeserver_ip command". At first, the time of the server equals the time server. However, when I looked at the ntpstat command afterwards, the number of milliseconds increased in the interim. Later the output of the ntpstat command was unsynchronized and I read -500.00 when I read the file /var/lib/ntp/drif.

here are the questions;

1- this problem reason is the using date command?

2- how can i reduce the difference?

3- How can I fix the drif file?

Comment: 1) No; 2) Determine the reason for the time drift. 3) What?

Comment: You basically need to determine the reason the server is time drifting away from the NTP time server.  Information provided doesn’t allow us to determine it

Comment: Could check which clocksource is used now & try switching it?

Comment: used clocksource is tsc, still /var/lib/ntp/drift 500.000 how could I continuous sync to the time server on this server?when I posted ntpstat command output is "time correct to within 450 ms", now 720ms. constantly increasing

Comment: @arifisik Can you please edit your question and show the output from `ntpq -pcrv`